# flash game engine selection of an awesome game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am thinking of developing of a game like this:
http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/429799
Do you have any idea - by which game engine I may develop this type of games? I am not sure whether I have to use any 3d physics engine?
I think JiglibFlash may be useful, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision model is all 2D. The graphics are 3D. You could use box2D to handle the collisions. Or frankly, a really simple circle-line collision system. Each point you click is a force that pushes away the ball, based on distance.

Here is an explanation of circle-line collision.
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/03/actionscript-collision-detection-2-circle-line-collision-detection/

As for the drawing, not sure how that was achieved. Its a nice effect.